# No weather information in the scopes

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes, weather

My BQ aquaris E5 no longer displays  weather information in the scopes. No information in the "the weather channel" scope and no weather information in the "today" scope.

Localization is on and the result is the same with wi-fi on and off line.

How can I reset the weather scopes?
SB